# JQ sorting key by arbitrary order

Tags: json, sorting, key, jq

I am trying to sort by key in an arbitrary format (key 'event' should be the first)

I know this one sort the key by alphabetical order:
jq -S '.' file.json

but is there a function to sort key so that the first one is always the same and not by alphabetical order?

It is to make them more human readable and have the most significant key first

Currently have: 
{key1:value, shouldbeFirstKey:value2, ...}
Would like
{shouldbeFirstKey:value2, key1:value, ...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a filter (derived from [walk/1](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#walk(f)) [[source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L284)]) which will reorder the keys of subobjects using a function:

```
def reorder(order):
    . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce (keys_unsorted|order)[] as $key(
        {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | reorder(order)) }
      )
    elif type == "array" then map( reorder(order) )
    else .
    end;
```

the order function is expected to return the set of keys in whatever order is desired.  e.g. the following function moves "shouldbeFirstKey" to the first position

```
def neworder:
    "shouldbeFirstKey" as $s
  | index($s) as $i
  | if $i==null then . else [$s] + .[:$i] + .[$i+1:] end
;
```

so that

```
  {key1:"value", shouldbeFirstKey:"value2", other:{key3:"value3", shouldbeFirstKey:"value4"}}
| reorder(neworder)
```

produces the output

```
{
  "shouldbeFirstKey": "value2",
  "key1": "value",
  "other": {
    "shouldbeFirstKey": "value4",
    "key3": "value3"
  }
}
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##dVDLboMwELznK1aIAygFKU1PRFx76ScgVJF4ozilNvWjaUT49dI1poFEig@rfXhmZ@f41fdAb@ECwz0olIqhioYYZ0PfvRQqDSEXY@MCfA/m3CDkOQRye8SdCcAcUFwRQFzM7hCiDzzrdyu0VAbZxTMX5UBIo2iGAGi7De1aQguRG8YZUMJF4YqS1t7qi6GboeNrjvVcXqVUdfbq4LNqojuSG5xGSKdSsM3ixh6BpwE0GRPog7Q12@IrV9q8IS1yh@nJKMHwJwp17B2cGxjyPBe2rr201K8vQl2SAWmRhdwnIV@ustKpGcAzSSNZS@assuC7qi0GT3CvaJw800jSJpW5/@uxu34MeAk6b@9k@//93rK@/5WN4VLoPkncIQkXjTVUqOqUSGuo@AM)

Comment: A clearer and no-more-inefficient version of neworder would be: def neworder:
  "shouldbeFirstKey" as $s
  | index($s) as $i
  | if $i==null then . else [$s] + .[:$i] + .[$i+1:] end
;

Comment: I've replaced my version of neworder with [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak)'s.  There's probably a better answer then this one out there if there are multiple keys to be reordered.  Also just using walk/1 as shown in the manual `jq 'walk(if type == "array" then sort else . end)'` for type "object" with an appropriate choice of `sort` might be simpler still.

Comment: Thanks for the update,
Just to understand, where should I define the function def neworder? I just started with jq, I want to run it from the command line. Cheers

Comment: I would put the defintions and the call to `reorder(neworder)` in a file (e.g. `filter.jq`) and use the [-f](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) option.  E.g. `jq -M -f filter.jq data.json`.

Comment: Should the neworder function call the reorder function? Am I missing something? I put the two function in filter.jq

Comment: `reorder` takes an expression to put the keys into the desired order.  In my example I defined a `neworder` function to do that and passed that function to `reorder`.

Comment: got it, so should I have a main in the filter.jq, i.e:def main():
    reorder(neworder)
; 
I need a jq tutorial I guess

Comment: There's no need for a main unless you want one. Your `filter.jq` could just have `def reorder:...; def neworder: ...; reorder(neworder)`

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have an object with a bunch of keys, and want some of those keys to appear in a certain order, while leaving the others as-is.  Then the technique illustrated by the following example can be used:

```
$ jq -n '{a:2,b:3,first:0,second:1} | . as $in | {first,second} + $in'
```

The result:

```
{
  "first": 0,
  "second": 1,
  "a": 2,
  "b": 3
}
```

#### rekey

Let's call the object defining the key ordering as the "template object" ({first,second} above).  Notice that using the technique described above, the keys in the "template object" always appear in the result.  If we only want the template object keys to appear in the result if they appear in the input, we can modify the above approach using the following function:

```
def rekey(obj):
  . as $in
  | reduce (obj|keys_unsorted)[] as $k ({};
      if $in|has($k) then . + {($k): $in[$k]} else . end)
  | . + $in ;
```

For example:

```
{a:2,b:3,first:0,second:1} | rekey({first,second,third})
```

produces:

```
{
  "first": 0,
  "second": 1,
  "a": 2,
  "b": 3
}
```

#### With `walk/1`

If one wants to reorder keys recursively, one can use `walk/1` (defined as at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq), 
as illustrated here using the above definition of `rekey`:

```
walk(if type == "object" then rekey($template) else . end)
```

where $template represents the "template object".

There is no need to define a special variant of `walk/1`. Simply define a function that takes as input an arbitrary object, and that produces the desired reordering.

(If your jq comes with the version of `walk/1` that uses `keys`, then you should consider updating your jq, or redefine `walk/1` to use `keys_unsorted`.)

Answer (score 0):

idea from @jq170727 's answer:

```
jq '
def reorder(a; n):
    def order(a; n):
        a as $a |
        n as $n |
        index($a) as $i |
        if $i == null then .
        else
            if $i<$n then .[:$i] + .[$i+1:$n+1] + [$a] + .[$n+1:]
            elif $n<$i then .[:$n] + [$a] + .[$n:]
            else .
            end
        end;

    . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce (keys_unsorted|order(a;n))[] as $key(
        {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | reorder(a; n)) }
      )
    elif type == "array" then map( reorder(a; n) )
    else .
    end;

[.[]  | reorder("id"; 0)| reorder("size"; 3) | reorder("name"; 1)]'
data.json
```